# How to migrate database from SAP DB to PostGres?

Tags: postgresql, migration, sybase, hana, maxdb

Any idea how to go about doing that through a tool(preferred). Any alternate ways to do that.

Comment: Which SAP database? HANA, Sybase/ASE, MaxDB, etc. Or do you mean a non-SAP database connected to SAP software/which ones?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the migration studio from EnterpriseDB [here](http://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/add-on-components-bundles), although I have no experience with it.

There is no comparison to doing it yourself though - if you're not familiar with Postgres then this will get you familiar, and if you are, then aside from the data entry aspect, this should be old hat.

Answer (score 1):

Use  [maxdb tools](http://maxdb.sap.com/doc/7_6/4e/a0bc40597a8431e10000000a1550b0/content.htm) to generate a SQL text export of the database. Then [import](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/backup.html) this file in PostgreSQL, luckily you won't need prior processing of the data dump.